# style.backgroundImage change overrides image transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a button for a player [(check video)](https://imgur.com/a/UAnpInu)

It works but to make the button seem "pressed" I have to change its background-image on click, however this seems to override the transtion that was already present. The part responsible for rotation still works, unlike image swapping.

Not changing the image on pause/changing it to the initial image does nothing.

I think the solution might be just to use @keyframes and do it all manually but I feel like there's a cleaner solution.

Here's a demo: (I need to make so when it's clicked twice the light-blue square still transitions back to orange)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let state = "pause";

    const playButton = document.getElementById("playIcon")

    function playButtonClick() {
        if (state === 'play') {
            state = 'pause';
            playButton.classList.remove("transitionBane");
            playButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/aliceblue/white')";
        } else {
            state = 'play';
            playButton.classList.add("transitionBane");
            playButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/gray/white')";
        }
    }

    addEventListener("click", playButtonClick)
});
```

```css
#playIcon {
  top: 35%;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white");
  button:focus {outline:0;}
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: 0;
  width: 18%;
  height: 31.6%;
  z-index: 52;
  transform: rotate(0);
  //animation: playButtonSwap1 2s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(.71,0,.33,1.56) 0ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#playIcon:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  background-image: url("https://placehold.co/600x400/aliceblue/white");
}

.transitionBane {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="playIcon"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked double click functionality and remove background image in hover selector here  as my understanding of your question Please check and let me know if this is not helpful for you.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let state = "pause";

    const playButton = document.getElementById("playIcon")

    function playButtonClick(event) {
        if (state === 'play') {
            state = 'pause';
            playButton.classList.remove("transitionBane");
            
            if(event.detail==1){
               playButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/aliceblue/white')";
            }
              if(event.detail==2){
               playButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white')";
            }
         
        } else {
            state = 'play';
            playButton.classList.add("transitionBane");
            playButton.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/gray/white')";
        }
    }

    addEventListener("click", playButtonClick)
});
```

```css
#playIcon {
  top: 35%;
  left: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/white");
  button:focus {outline:0;}
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: 0;
  width: 18%;
  height: 31.6%;
  z-index: 52;
  transform: rotate(0);
  //animation: playButtonSwap1 2s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.75s cubic-bezier(.71,0,.33,1.56) 0ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#playIcon:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);

}

.transitionBane {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="playIcon"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was not quite the solution but it showed me a way to do what I want, check it out in the codepen: https://codepen.io/Maksiks/pen/xxQybVm . I also now accidentally know how to add double click functionality, thank you for that. Also please edit the answer with the code from the codepen, there are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow to edit it myself as I am writing this.

Comment: sure @Maksiks i will check